# sqlite3 Error Executing SQL From File

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to create tables in an SQLite database with sqlite3.

The command `$ sqlite3 mydb < mytables.sql`  produce the following error:  `Incomplete SQL: ??C`.

mytables.sql is:

```
CREATE TABLE SizeCulture (
    SizeCultureID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
    SizeID INTEGER NULL,
    CultureID TEXT NULL,
    Name TEXT NULL,
    Description TEXT NULL,
    Abbreviation TEXT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Size(
    SizeID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC ,
    Creation TEXT NOT NULL,
    Modification TEXT NOT NULL,
    Deleted INTEGER NOT NULL,
);
/****** Object:  Table [Ordering].[BarCode]    Script Date: 11/09/2011 14:58:19 ******/
CREATE TABLE BarCode(
    BarCodeID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC NOT NULL,
    BarCodeValue TEXT NOT NULL,
);
```

This was modified from a script generated by SQL Server, where some tables need to be replicated on an Android device.

The above is just a set of repeating create table statements.  From what I understand, SQLite follows standard SQL (like MySQL or postgres).

Answer (score 2):

Though I can't test it at the moment, I think it's the trailing commas that are confusing it (for example, the comma at the end of `Abbreviation TEXT NULL,`). Try removing all those trailing commas.

**Edit:** To be clear, I'm talking about all of these commas:

```
Abbreviation TEXT NULL,
...
Deleted INTEGER NOT NULL,
...
BarCodeValue TEXT NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Tried that.  I'm still getting the same error.  There a few tables that reference a another table as the last line (or 2 lines in some cases).

Comment: @Mike: It works fine if you remove the stray trailing commas. Is there more to the SQL file than you're showing us?

Comment: @muistooshort  The only thing that is not shown is 130 lines of creates statements for brevity.  Create statements are that is in the fiel.  I have removed the trailing commas, comments, and foreign key statements.  I'm in the process of checking each create statement.

Comment: I ran the above command on the Android emulator through appropriate java classes, yet it only created the first table.  Trying to create a test database through the OSX Terminal still results in the above error.

Comment: Make sure every statement has a semicolon at the end of it. I know it may not be a problem in your case, but I got the same error so if one of your create statements is missing it, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but for a different reason (so I'm commenting because Google led me here). Turns out you can also encounter this error if your file has a weird encoding (like UCS-2 instead of UTF8).